# Save form when using rails3-jquery-autocomplete

Tags: jquery, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-3, autocomplete

I am new to ROR and am wondering what I am doing wrong.

I have the following Models:

**User Model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :intros
has_many :contacts
```

**Intro Model**

```
class Intro < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
```

**Contact Model**

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
```

The users have a form in **views/intros/_form.html.erb** where their contacts are showing up via autocomplete via Gem 'rails3-jquery-autocomplete'. The autocomplete is working great.

I followed the instructions for the gem and replaced 
`f.text_field :person1_name` with

```
<%= f.autocomplete_field :contact_name, autocomplete_contact_name_intros_path, :placeholder   => "Name:", :class => 'input_field' %>
```

My Question:

I am trying to get this form to save to f.text_field so that I can use them in **/views/intros/show.html.erb** but I am not sure how that works.

They are supposed to be saved to :person1_name which I should then be able to pull up as `<%= @intro.person1_name %>` but I don't know how to save the form.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this:

I didn't realize the obvious:
I was following the gem README file to a fault which shows **:contact_name** as the default attribute. I thought that was necessary for the gem to work. However I soon realized you have to replace **:contact_name** with your own attribute, so in my case:

**BEFORE**

`<%= f.autocomplete_field :contact_name, autocomplete_contact_name_intros_path, :placeholder   => "Name:", :class => 'input_field' %>`

**AFTER**

```
<%= f.autocomplete_field :person_name1, autocomplete_contact_name_intros_path, :placeholder   => "Name:", :class => 'input_field' %>
```